# ng-class $event.stopPropagation() not working on parent in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 nested `ng-repeats`. The parent one adds a class to itself based on `ng-click`, however when I click the child it is still happening when I thought it shouldnt.

```
<div class="add-filter-tags" data-filter="{{f1}}" ng-class="{'tag_selected' : tag_selected }" ng-repeat="(f1,f2) in filters" ng-click="tag_selected = !tag_selected;">
            <span>{{f1}}</span>             
        <div class="add-filter-tags sub-filter-tag"  data-filter="{{f1_2}}"  ng-click="$parent.$event.stopPropagation()" ng-repeat="(f1_2,f2_2) in filters[f1]" sibs ><span>{{f1_2}}</span></div>

</div>
```

EDIT: I have also tried it without `$parent` and its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop event propagation on the child so that it does not bubble up to the parent, there will be no `$event` object attached to the `$parent` as well. It is a special argument passed in with `ng-click` i.e

```
 ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.tag_selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="add-filter-tags" ng-class="{'tag_selected' : tag_selected }" ng-if="true" ng-click="tag_selected = !tag_selected;">
    <span>Parent</span> 
    <div class="add-filter-tags sub-filter-tag" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-if="true"><span>Child</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, I pasted that code in there but I was originally trying it withou `$parent` and it wasnt working

Comment: See my demo.., click on child and see it wont toggle the class.

Comment: ok, sorry, I caused a bit of confusion here, you are correct in that the lack of parent was causing the issue, the reason it wasnt working for me was actually to do with an error in the directive.